# let - copies the value in memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-management

```
function btFun(){
  var arr = [];

  for (var i =0; i<3; i++){
    let j = i;
    arr.push(
      function(){
        console.log(j);
      }
    )
  }

  return arr;
}
```

I have question that involves `let`. When I execute the functions created with this code, I get 
`0` , `1`, `2`. And does that mean that `let` did create a copy value of that `i` iterator somewhere in memory and for each function it created reference to them?

[image]

Comment: The scope of `let` is the block, and each iteration introduces a new scope.

Comment: I think you want to look into "block scoping" http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html How it is stored internally, is up to the JS Engine

Comment: Right - it's not so much something that `let` does; it just gives you access to the scope that's already there (in modern JavaScript runtimes).

Comment: Can someone recommend some entry to see how it does and not what it does?